# Django 1.8 migration error with postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new to Django  and I am trying to create table in Postgre using Django(1.8)

following is my model class

```
    class Student(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        degree = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        numofsubs = models.IntegerField()
        namesofsubs= models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        details = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Meta:

      db_table = "student"
```

views.py

```
def addStudent(request):
    student = Student(name = request.name, degree = request.degree ,
     numofsubs = request.numofsubs , nameofsubs = request.nameofparams , details = request.details)
    student.save()
    print 'data saved'
```

After these changes when I tried to run python manage.py migrate i got `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_migrations`

following are the stack traces

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 338, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 330, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 390, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 441, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
>   line 93, in handle
>       executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)   File
>   "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
>   line 19, in **init**
>       self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
>   line 47, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
>   line 180, in build_graph
>       self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
>   line 60, in applied_migrations
>       return set(tuple(x) for x in self.migration_qs.values_list("app", "name"))   File
>   "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 162, in **iter**
>       self._fetch_all()   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 965, in _fetch_all
>       self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 1220, in iterator
>       for row in compiler.results_iter():   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
>   line 783, in results_iter
>       results = self.execute_sql(MULTI)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
>   line 829, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 79, in execute
>       return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 97, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation
>   django_migrations

My  `settings.py` has following conf for db conection

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'abc',
        'USER': 'xyz',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Please guide me whats wrong with my app.

Thanks

Comment: did you create postgres database with your django user as owner?

Comment: I created db while installing postgres via shel , and now i want to connect to that db through django and create and insert data in table

Comment: can you test local connection `psql -h localhost -U xyz abc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to allow grands to your user:

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE abc TO xyz;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest to do a GRANT ALL. However, as Bear Brown pointed out, it sounds like it's down to permissions, so make sure you at least have USAGE for relevant schema and the SELECT privilege for the table. First connect to the abc database, and then grant the select privilege on public:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO xyz
```